# Does automatic tuning revise the plan decision?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022, automatic-tuning

When automatic tuning is enabled, using SET AUTOMATIC_TUNING(FORCE_LAST_GOOD_PLAN), then based on query regression suppose SQL server auto decides to force a plan, then when does it revisit it's decision and reassess whether or not there is a better plan that can execute the query faster/with less resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of.

Details about automatic tuning are shown in this DMV:
[sys.dm_db_tuning_recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-tuning-recommendations-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

When there is a change that would affect the forced plan, it's propagated into the **state** column.

Documentation provides the full list, but examples are:

> SchemaChanged
> Recommendation expired because the schema of a referenced table is changed. New recommendation will be created if a new query plan regression is detected on the new schema.

> StatisticsChanged
> Recommendation expired due to the statistic change on a referenced table. New recommendation will be created if a new query plan regression is detected based on new statistics.